# Swift function returning unusable optional

Tags: function, swift, option-type, any

I have the below function that returns `Any?` here, I am simplifying the code to make the problem clear.

```
func myFoo(index:CInt, type:CInt, stmt:COpaquePointer) -> Any? { return nil }
```

In the below sample code, the value is supposed to be `nil` which is not happening the block of code inside the if-statement is executed.

```
let value : Any? = self.myFoo(index, type: type, stmt: stmt)

if value
{
   // below is entered!!
}
```

the debugger shows the values as

> value protocol<>? Some    Some    Some    Swift._Nil  nil

Comment: what is your question here? your code is working well, it returns `nil`. the debugger shows the proper `nil` value... where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: the if condition is not working, the if block is entered i.e: the if condition is resulting to true while the value is nil

Comment: what you are saying is not happening ever. if the `value` is `nil` the _if_ statement will never run into the true-branch. you may need to crarifiy your question and problem more precisely.

Comment: this is exactly what is going on. try is and see. if you change the function return type to any type other than Any? the if condition will work properly, the problem occurs only when the function returns Any?

Comment: this shows the problem in a more simplified way. i removed the function and tried it directly and the problem is occurs:
     
let value : Any? = nil
     
if value
{
 // this block of code just not be entered! well, it is!!
}

Comment: before I wrote my very first comment I've tried your code, so I can confirm what your are saying here is not happening. the true-branch won't be performed at all if the `value` is `nil`.

Comment: let x : String? = nil
     
if x
{
// block not entered, this works fine with any type other than Any?
}

Comment: you may want to extend your comparison like `if values == nil { ... }`...

Comment: @holex: did you try it with return type Any?

Comment: yes, I told you I've tried... have you tried to extend you `if` statement and check it, please?

Comment: let x : Any? = nil
     
if x != nil { // you should NOT be here now!!  }

Comment: you may need to check what `Any` refers before you continue that discussion...

Comment: yes i tried it. same problem. i just copied your code as it is and the block of the if statement is entered

Comment: page 245 of apple's iBook "the swift programming language", the Any data type is defined: “Any can represent an instance of any type at all”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/lb/jEUH0.l

Comment: that is more interesting for you, _The Bacics_, I reckon, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399 section _Optionals_ and section _nil_, it may help to understand you, why the `Any` is not `nil` (as pointer), and why the `nil` 'd rather be the _absence of valid value_ here then a `nil` (as pointer). I quit.

Comment: I Changed Any? to AnyObject? and it works fine now. thanks for your help.